# Git Merge Abort in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I was trying to do a merge in Eclipse, but it got messed up somehow.

I would therefore like to abort the merge and start all over again.

In Git Bash, I would simply execute:

```
 git merge --abort
```

However, I am using a machine where no Git Bash is installed. How can I do that in Eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried reset option in git , where you can change your head to previous commit !

Comment: How on earth were you trying to merge something if you don't have `git` ?

Comment: @Ksyqo Eclipse uses a pure Java implementation of Git called JGit; it is not required to install the official git binaries to use it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000319/egit-cannot-checkout-now-stuck-in-rebase-state/34001313#34001313).